# Write irssi scripts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, perl

Is it at all possible to write [irssi](http://irssi.org/) scripts in Ruby instead of Perl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, [irssi only allows for Perl scripting](http://juerd.nl/site.plp/irssiscripttut). But fwiw, [WeeChat provides for scripting in Ruby and 4 other languages](http://www.weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_scripting.en.html#introduction).

Comment: marcog: the truth can be harsh to some people.